# Why does the countif function only works if I am in the same worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I hope someone can help me. 
I've got two columns with reference numbers in column C and N in one worksheet in excel.

column C:
AAAA1
ABAA3
KDFG4
...

Column N:
ABAA2
AAAA4
MMMM3
...

Then I add the formula 'left' into the columns A and L to cut off the right number from the reference numbers in columns C and N :

```
 Dim lastrow As Long  
  Worksheets(sheet).Cells(2, column - 1).Formula = "=LEFT(" & Worksheets(sheet).Cells(2, column - 1).Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0) & ",6)"  
lastrow = Worksheets("AAL").Cells(Worksheets(sheet).rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).row  
Worksheets(sheet).Cells(2, column - 1).Resize(lastrow - 1).FillDown
```

column A:
AAAA
ABAA
KDFG
...

Column L:
ABAA
AAAA
MMMM
...

Afterwards I use the following code to add the missing reference numbers from the column L at the bottom of column A:

```
 Worksheets(sheet).Calculate  
Dim Rw As Long, Rw2 As Long, iFound As Integer  
Rw2 = Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Worksheets(sheet).rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1  

For Rw = 2 To Worksheets(sheet).Cells(rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).row  
 iFound = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Rw, 12))  
 If iFound = 0 Then  
   Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Rw2, 1).Value = Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Rw, 12).Value   
   Rw2 = Rw2 + 1  
 End If  
Next Rw
```

The weird thing is that if I have the worksheet 'sheet' open, the code works absolutely fine. However if I am on a different worksheet when I run the VBA code, the code adds **all** values from column L at the bottom of column A, not just 'MMMM'.

It looks like  the formula left from the first query doesn't properly calculate unless you open the excel sheet. But I thought the code

```
Worksheets(sheet).Calculate
```

will do exactly that.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Note that reference to range is direct here, `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Rw, 12))`, if you want to run your macro from various sheets try referencing indirectly, like `Worksheet(sheet).Range(A:A)`. Think you just missed that part.

Comment: If I leave the " away, I get a compile error.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Worksheet(sheet).Range("A:A")`. I meant, that you should also include sheet in this reference.

Comment: Amazing. This fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheets(sheet).Cells(2, column - 1).Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0)` will only return the cell range and will not include the sheet reference.

You need to add the external reference:

```
Worksheets("sheet").Cells(2, Column - 1).Offset(0, 2).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the line as you suggested, but it still adds all columns from column L at the bottom of column A, if I don't have the sheet open.